# Rails 5: How to send a post request for multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, post, ruby-on-rails-5

This is what I am trying to do:

```
= form_tag(path) do
    - @items.each do |i|
        = fields_for "i[]", i do
            %input.content{:name => "content", :type => "hidden"}
    = submit_tag "Submit"
```

As you can see, I try to pass the value of all `.content` inputs from `items`to a path.
These are the parameters I get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "content"=>"", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

I'd expect something like this:

```
{"items": [
    {
        "id":1,
        "content":""
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "content":""
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "content":""
    },
] }
```

How do you create those POST requests in rails?

Comment: `fields_for "i[]"` `fields_for` tends to expect an actual Active Record type (eg `fields_for @user` - not a string that is the field-name. Here's the api dock on this (it has examples): http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: I tried something like this `= simple_form_for @items, :url => path do |f|
    %input.content{:name => "content", :type => "hidden"}
    = submit_tag "Submit"`, but now I get `undefined method `to_key'` error for `@items`

Comment: How about something simpler: `- @items.each do |i|`  `hidden_field_tag :value => "items[#{i.id}]", i.content` `end`

Comment: hm, it complains about the `i.content` as a SyntaxError. I don't find the opportunity to pass the second value.

Comment: Is this a stupid solution: `- @snippets.each do |s|    = hidden_field_tag :value => s.id.to_s + "-dfgdfgbdxfgbfgnbcfgngfncfgnghnghng"` ?

Comment: @johnhue - yes I haven't bug-fixed it - just wrote a rough guide int eh comment... my point is - if it's just a single hidden field per item... you can just add a single hidden field per item, rather than using fields_for

Comment: I'd avoid trying to shove all the data into the field-name. Use the id in the field name (to identify which item it is), and put the content in the value of the field. Looks like you don't need `:value =>` for that (my bad), just pass it as the second argument. So eg something like: `hidden_field_tag "items[#{i.id}]", i.content ` here's the doc for it: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag

Comment: Ok so that works thank you! How would I then process these parameters: `"items"=>{"38383285"=>"", "304713261"=>"", "547539357"=>""}` on the server. I basically want to loop through each record and apply changes.

Comment: To be more precise: If I have this: `params[:items].each do |i|
            item = Item.find(i)` How would I access the value attached to the item id?

Comment: Let me turn that into an answer... but really - you loop through the things and apply the change if there is one :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler than you've been trying to make it. You tend to only need `fields_for` if you have a set of fields for each of the nested models. here you just have a single hidden column, so I'd choose to just use a single hidden field eg:

```
= form_tag(path) do |f|
    - @items.each do |i|
      = f.hidden_field "items[#{i.id}]", value: i.content
    = submit_tag "Submit"
```

Note: not bug-testing left as an exercise to the reader.

This will generate a set of parameters that map the id of the item vs the content eg: `"items"=>{"38383285"=>"", "304713261"=>"Some content here", "547539357"=>"Some other content here"}`

Which you can just iterate through to change the actual values however you like.

You have not provided any example of the actual structure of your models - so I am guessing how you would use that... you will need to (possibly heavily) modify the example below to meet your actual needs.
For one thing - given it's a hidden field - I have no idea what other model (and column) it is that you are trying to update. So lets pretend you have a second model called `OtherItem` that also has a content-field and maps to an `Item` via an `item_id` column. In that case, you'd do something like this:

```
def my_action
  item_ids = params[:items].keys
  items = OtherItem.where(:item_id => item_ids)
  items.each do |item|
    item.update(content: params[:items][item.item_id])
  end
  # other stuff here
```

end